# Grails Databinding: no effect on domainInstance.properties = params

Tags: grails, data-binding

I'm using Grails 2.2.2.
I have a Domain named "Table" and a autogenerated controller TableController. The Problem is, that "update" action has no effect.

```
def update = {
    def tableInstance = Table.get(params.id)
    println params.definition
    if (tableInstance) {
        if (params.version) {
            def version = params.version.toLong()
            if (tableInstance.version > version) {

                tableInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure", [message(code: 'table.label', default: 'Table')] as Object[], "Another user has updated this Table while you were editing")
                render(view: "edit", model: [tableInstance: tableInstance])
                return
            }
        }
        tableInstance.properties = params
        println tableInstance.definition
        if (!tableInstance.hasErrors() && tableInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'table.label', default: 'Table'), tableInstance.id])}"
            redirect(action: "show", id: tableInstance.id)
        }
        else {
            render(view: "edit", model: [tableInstance: tableInstance])
        }
    }
    else {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'table.label', default: 'Table'), params.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
}
```

The first println has output: "newValue"
The second pringln has output: "oldValue".

It seams, that the dataBinding in the following line doesn't work:

```
tableInstance.properties = params
```

In the Grails Verions 1.3.7 it works as expected.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that the property is transient. In Grails 2.x the transient properties are not binded anymore, due to security issue.
[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297401/grails-transient-properties-not-picked-up-on-object-creation)